# $A$ is dense in $[0,1]$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $A$ then the integral is zero

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

I need to prove the following:

Let $A$ be a dense set in $[0,1]$.Suppose $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann  integrable and $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in A$. Show that $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)  dx=0$

My attempt:

Intuively we check this, because if we have that a set $A$ is dense in $[0,1]$, then we have "a lot of points of $A$ in $[0,1]$", then we can see that "$A$ almost covers all $[0,1]$", thus if $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in A$ then it is almost in $[0,1]$ therefore $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)  dx=0$ .

But the thing is to say this formally and to verify that this is correct. Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: Are you using Riemann or Lebesgue integrals? The Dirichlet function is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: Is this integrable in the sense of Riemann or Lebesgue?  Because in the sense of Lebesgue, then one could provide a counter-example, namely $f(x) = \chi_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$.

Comment: Riemman integrable :)

Comment: I have corrected :) Riemann integrable :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is Riemann integrable, then all its Riemann sum converge to $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$.

Then consider one particular Riemann sum, i.e. for the subdivsion $\{0=x_0< x_1 <\cdots < x_n = 1\}$, in each subinterval $[x_i, x_{i+1}]$, we take one point in $\xi_i \in A$ for the Riemann sum, then the Riemann sum is always zero, i.e.
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(\xi_i)(x_{i+1}- x_i) = 0$$
so is its limit.

Comment: An Can I say it like that ? or How Can I write formaly ? Thank you a lot :)

Comment: Thanks then we are done with this isnt?

Comment: @user162343 yes, I've edited, hope now it's more clear.

Comment: Well this is the proof :) thank you, and was my intuition right ?

Comment: @user162343 Well, basically this proof is a formalization of the intuition you formulated

Comment: @user162343 It depends on how you mean by $almost$. As is shown in Lolman's answer, if we ignore the Riemann intergrability condtion, $f$ can be non null in a subset of positive measure

Comment: Thank you a lot, and how can I be more formal in this stuff? , Is because is difficult for me :)

Comment: @user162343 You have good intuition, to be formal you just need to express your idea rigorously through the definition of Riemann integral and show that how the given condition combined with the definition lead to the result

Comment: Thank you, well with your answer you answer to me that part :)

Comment: @user162343 you are welcome, glad to help :)

Comment: Thank you a lot, I liked your simple proof :)

Answer (score 2):

Since for any partition of $[0,1]$ you can find an identically zero Riemann sum (due to the fact that $A$ is dense), zero is the only real number that fulfills the integrability criteria!

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{edit:}$ I answered before the question got modified asking for a Riemann integrable function. But just for an integrable function.

It is false. Take $A=\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ and $B=[0,1]\cap A^c$ and define: $$f(x)=\chi_B(x)$$ as the characteristic function of $B$. As you can see $f(x)=0$ on a dense subset, but $$\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=1.$$

Comment: $f$ is not Riemann integrable...

Comment: The question was edited.